# Ext JS: Why can not call array from another class' property/function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, extjs, panel

I'm trying to achieve different `items` depends on logged user within `initComponent` property but I'm not able to call and render `aDashItems` and `bDashItems` arrays. I've tried to call as property and as function but couldn't be success!

Below you'll find the `AllItems` class as well. What exactly i am doing wrong here?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MainDash', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.maindash',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.AllItems'
    ],

    closable: true,
    layout: 'responsivecolumn',
    bodyPadding: 20,
    scrollable: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        var username = localStorage.getItem("username");

        var aDashItems = MyApp.AllItems.aDashItems;
        var bDashItems = MyApp.AllItems.bDashItems;
        // var aDashItems = MyApp.AllItems.aDashItems();
        // var bDashItems = MyApp.AllItems.bDashItems();

        // Dashboard "A";
        if (username === "abc" || username.match(/regEx/)) {
            me.items = [aDashItems];
        }
            // Dashboard "B";
            else if (username === "cba") {
                me.items = [bDashItems];
            }

        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Called class;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.AllItems', {
    requires: [...],

    aDashItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'widgetA' 
        },
        // some other items...
    ],
    // aDashItems: function () {
    //     var me = this;
    //
    //     me.items = [
    //         [
    //             {
    //                 xtype: 'widgetA' 
    //             },
    //             // some other items...
    //         ]
    //     ];
    //
    //     return me.items;
    // },

    bDashItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'widgetA'
        },
        // some other items...
    ]
    // bDashItems: function () {
    //     var me = this;
    //
    //     me.items = [
    //         {
    //               xtype: 'widgetB'
    //         },
    //         // some other items...  
    //     ];
    //
    //     return me.items;
    // }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ExtJS

You could create `MyApp.AllItems` as a *[`singleton`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-singleton)* and you can access same class throughout the application using that class name.

> When any class set to true, the class will be instantiated as singleton.

For example:

```
Ext.define('App.utils.Constants', {
    singleton: true,

    alternateClassName: 'constants',

    config: {
        text: 'Demo' //This will getter and setter
    },

    log: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    }
});

//Access value like this 
constants.log('Hello');//output "Hello"

constants.getText();//output "Demo"
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fpa)**, I have created a demo. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define("MyApp.AllItems", {
            singleton: true,
            alternateClassName: 'alltems',
            config: {
                aDashItems: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Dashbord A'
                }],
                bDashItems: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Dashbord B'
                }]
            },

            constructor: function (config) {
                this.initConfig(config);
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MyApp.MainDash', {

            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

            title: 'Demo',

            alias: 'widget.maindash',

            closable: true,

            bodyPadding: 20,

            scrollable: true,

            initComponent: function () {
                var me = this,
                    username = 'cba';

                me.callParent();
                // Dashboard "A";
                if (username === "abc") {
                    me.add(alltems.getADashItems());
                }
                // Dashboard "B";
                else if (username === "cba") {
                    me.add(alltems.getBDashItems());
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'maindash',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: it works and doing several XHR request successfully. **But** somehow I'm not able to see `view`. It's not rendering `view`! Couldn't figure out why is that..

Comment: @NuriEngin could you please check console is there any log or try to inspect ?

Comment: it's giving any error. As well all required XHR request are being success related with items. Also `me.add(allItems.getADashItems())` function seems like work, whole items listed below. But none of view rendering =(

Comment: Just the thing when `me.callParent()` of `panel` above the `if else` statment that recognise logged user, then it's doing required XHR but when it's below it's not doing XHR as well. Both way doesn't render views.

Comment: ok just try without `initComponent` and check that items(means directly add on items config) are work or not. If it is work that means some issue with `initComponent` otherwise may be with view layout issue.

Comment: Not yet. I've tried constructor and some other easy setups but still can not render view. I've understood the working-flow with singleton class but somehow it's resist to display...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? so I can try to resolve your issue

Comment: Sure, I'll try it as well and inform you here back. Thanks.

Comment: I found the reason for error. I've implemented a `button` somehow it's `render/beforerender` type `listeners` doesn't let whole view display.

Comment: Couldn't prepare a fiddle.. currently working on issue to solve problem. FYI.

Comment: Ok try to solve if there is any issue then you can again put message here